# Use of "as" to mean "like" -- "nothing occurs if I click on the button as there is no button there"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I wrote:

> the button doesn't get highlighted as the mouse hover it and nothing occurs if I click on the button **as there is no button there/as it is not a button**

By the bold phrase I want to say, the button doesn't respond as you expect, so you may think it is not a button or it is disabled. Am I correctly used "as"? What are other ways to say such sentence?

Comment: I'm not getting this--how can you click on a button that isn't there? And what would induce you to click on an invisible button?

Comment: @StoneyB - he asks whether we can use **as** as **like**. "as if there were no button there".

Comment: @StoneyB I wanted to say, it doesn't respond and doesn't act like a normal button, as if it were not a button!

Comment: Aside from @StoneyB comment, it should and  must be "mouse pointer/cursor." as pointed by CopperKettle. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the construction "**as if there were no**"

> The button doesn't get highlighted when the mouse cursor hovers over it, and nothing occurs if I click on the button, **as if there were** no button there.

Or:

> The button doesn't get highlighted when the mouse cursor hovers over it, and nothing occurs if I click on the button, **as if it were** not a button.

In the examples above, I employed *[the subjunctive form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)*: "as if it **were**", but you can retain the indicative form: **is**

> The button doesn't get highlighted when the mouse cursor hovers over it, and nothing occurs if I click on the button, as if there **is** no button there.

---

The crucial thing is to use not just **as** but **as if**. Compare:

> She's spending money **like** there's no tomorrow. (okay)
>
> She's spending money **as** there's no tomorrow. (not okay: the meaning has changed)
>
> She's spending money **as if** there's no tomorrow. (okay)